# for each loop breaking before array complete

Tags: javascript, for-of-loop

I have a simple function looks at an object in an array. If it doesn't find a match based on a property it checks if it has children and then checks each of those for a property value.

It seems to work as expected through the first object with children, however it is not hitting that third layer.

The object is something like this:

```js
 data = [{
    title: 'Home',
    route: '/reports/home',
  },
  {
   title: 'Layer 2',
   children: [
     { title: 'Title 1', route: '/reports/title1' },
     { title: 'Title 2', route: '/reports/title2' },
   ],
  },
  {
    title: 'Layer 3',
    children: [
      { title: 'Title 3', route: '/reports/title3' },
      { title: 'Title 4', route: '/reports/title4' },
    ],
  }];


lookUpTitle = navGroup => {
  for (let item of navGroup) {
    if (item.route && item.route.toLowerCase() === '/reports/title3') {
      console.log(item.title)
      return item.title;
    } else {
      if (item.children) {
        return this.lookUpTitle(item.children);
      }
    }
  }
};
    
lookUpTitle(data)
```

I'm simply calling the function and passing in the array as  above.

I can find Title 2 just fine, but the function will not iterate through to the third object in the array if I'm looking for Title 3 or 4. What am I missing?

Comment: When you `return` from a loop, the whole function will end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What is happening**

To understand why the loop stops, let's write what is happening step by step:

1. `item` takes the value of the first object. (Title = Home).
2. The `if` condition is not met and `item` doesn't contain `children`
3. `item` takes the value of the second object.
4. The `if` condition is not met but `item` contains `children`
5. The function returns the result of the function call `lookUpTitle()` thus the loop stops.
6. Go back to step 1 but with the children values of your second object.

So the loop will always stop if an object doesn't meet the `if` condition and contains `children`.

**How to fix it**

In order to fix it, we have to track the recursive results. Check if a result is found through the recursive call of `lookUpTitle()`. If not, continue to loop, if found, you can return it. This method assumes you only want the first result found and not all existing results.

```js
lookUpTitle = navGroup => {
  for (let item of navGroup) {
    if (item.route && item.route.toLowerCase() === '/reports/title3') {
      return item.title;
    } else {
      if (item.children) {
        var res = this.lookUpTitle(item.children);
        if(res != undefined)
          return res;
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

there is problem , that is because of `return`

```
         if (item.children) {
            //from here it will come out as its return 
             return this.lookUpTitle(item.children);
          }
```

try like this

```
lookUpTitle = navGroup => {
      const title =[];
      for (let item of navGroup) {
        if (item.route && item.route.toLowerCase() === '/reports/title3') {
          console.log(item.title)
          return item.title;
        } else {
          if (item.children) {
            this.lookUpTitle(item.children);
          } else {
            console.log(item.title);
            return item.title;
          }
        }
      }
    };
```

Comment: without the return it can't find anything even in the second object

Answer (score 0):

If the for loop iterates thru an item that has children (as the 2nd one does) it will always return a value, exiting the for loop.

For the "else" clause, you need to check whether lookUpTitle actually found the desired title.  If so, return it, if not, continue the for loop.